# how to create drop down attributes for customer

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

I want to introduce a new field in customer admin area and I just want to have it two options "yes" or "no"

here is my code that is creating simple text fields but I am not sure how can I create drop down attribute for the customer?

```
$installer->startSetup();
$vCustomerEntityType = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$vCustAttributeSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($vCustomerEntityType);
$vCustAttributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($vCustomerEntityType,$vCustAttributeSetId);
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'testveri', array(
    'label' => 'Working?',
    'input' => 'text',
    'type'  => 'varchar',
    'forms' => array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'),
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
));
$installer->addAttributeToGroup($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId,     $vCustAttributeGroupId, 'testveri', 0);
$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'testveri');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'));
$oAttribute->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

Can anybody help me in creating a drop down attribute for admin panel only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'testveri', array(
    'label' => 'Working?',
    'input' => 'select',
    'type'  => 'int',
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    'option' => array('values' => array('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3')) 
));
```

**EDIT**
Add the new attribute as a column in the grid.
Override the default customer grid and in `_prepareColumns` add this:

```
protected function _prepareColumns(){ 
    $values = array(
        1   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Yes'),
        0   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('No') 
    );
    $this->addColumnAfter('testveri', array( 
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Working?'), 
        'index' => 'testveri', 
        'type'      =>  'options',
        'options'   =>  $values, 
    ),'email'); 
    return parent::_prepareColumns(); 
}
```

Comment: Its having one issue. its not showing values as Yes or no instead its showing the value IDs i.e. for yes its showing 5 and for "no" its showing 6

Comment: If you want a yes/no attribute change the `source` in the code above to `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean` and remove `option`.

Comment: no it doesn't work still now it have started showing 1 or 0 but still not Yes or no :( please help

Comment: Where do you get 1 and 0? in the form or when displaying it somewhere? Can you post the full code of your module and indicate where the problem occurs?

Comment: I am getting  1 and 0 on the customer grid. I am adding the column on the customer grid.

 protected function _prepareColumns(){
        $this->addColumnAfter('testveri', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Working?'),
            'index'     => 'testveri',
        ),'email');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

Comment: however on adding / editing customer I am seeing Yes / no

Comment: can you please help ??

Comment: I've edited my answer, because it was too much code to put in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to add drop-down value attribute for customer

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

/* @var $installer Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'testveri', array(
    'label'        => 'Working?',
    'visible'      => true,
    'required'     => false,
    'type'         => 'int',
    'input'        => 'select',
    'source'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
));


$tableOptions        = $installer->getTable('eav_attribute_option');
$tableOptionValues   = $installer->getTable('eav_attribute_option_value');

// add options for level of politeness
$attributeId = (int)$installer->getAttribute('customer', 'testveri', 'attribute_id');
foreach (array('Yes', 'No') as $sortOrder => $label) {

    // add option
    $data = array(
        'attribute_id' => $attributeId,
        'sort_order'   => $sortOrder,
    );
    $installer->getConnection()->insert($tableOptions, $data);

    // add option label
    $optionId = (int)$installer->getConnection()->lastInsertId($tableOptions, 'option_id');
    $data = array(
        'option_id' => $optionId,
        'store_id'  => 0,
        'value'     => $label,
    );
    $installer->getConnection()->insert($tableOptionValues, $data);

}

$genderAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'testveri');
$genderAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
     'adminhtml_customer',
     'customer_address_edit',
     'customer_register_address'
));
$genderAttribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'testveri', array(
    'label' => 'Working?',
    'input' => 'select',
    'type'  => 'int',
    'source'  => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
));

$attributeCode='testveri';
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', $attributeCode);
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));
$attribute->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend i have found some small and Quick solution for creating attribute for customer.

Login your Admin and follow the stapes.

Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage Attributes

Now create an attribute. It might be text box or drop down

Now open your phpmyadmin & find out **eav_attribute** table
Now find out your attribute with your attribute_code
and change entity_type_id with 1. Because 1 stand for customer attribute.

Now from any controller just run the following code

```
$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'your attribute code');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'));
$oAttribute->save();
```